# How to access contact information outside salesforce environment

Tags: javascript-remoting

I want to access salesforce data like(contact information ) outside salesforce environment in javascript how i can access salesforce data. I have a javascript file on my computer now i want to retrive salesforce contact in my javascript and show on html page how i can accomplish this task i have urgent requirement to complete task.(any help appriciable)Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. What have you tried so far and where abouts are you stuck on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Mohan,

there are few good javascript libraries that will help you to integrate with salesforce and access the data using REST APIs..

here's a good start for integrating force.com via javascript 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/JavaScript

you can use the [Force.com JavaScript REST Toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit)

Comment: I don't want to use visualforc page.

Comment: u dont need VF to use this. these libraries / toolkits are to access salesforce from external systems with javascript

Comment: I tried but i can't success , what i have to fill on below field:                     var loginUrl    = 'https://login.salesforce.com/';
        var clientId    = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
        var redirectUri = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_APP/oauthcallback.html';
        var proxyUrl    = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_APP/proxy.php?mode=native';